# Adding option elements using .innerHTML in IE is not working

Tags: javascript

I have a variable ddEmail having value

```
<option value="cp@cp.ljj" selected="">cp@cp.ljj</option>.
```

When I try to put it in select element using

```
document.getElementById("txtEmail").innerHTML = ddEmail;
```

then in Firefox `document.getElementById("txtEmail").innerHTML` shows me the same value as of `ddEmail` while in IE it shows `cp@cp.ljj</option>`

Is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't reliably use `innerHTML` to set the options of an existing `select`.

The best way it through the `select`'s `options` property:

```
var option = new Option("cb@cb.ljj", "cb@cb.ljj");
//  Option text --------^            ^---- option value
option.selected = true;
document.getElementById("txtEmail").options.add(option);
```

Note that for historical reasons, it's `add`, not `push`. `push` works on *lots* of browsers, but not all of them.

Also note that the above assumes that either there are no options in the `select`, or you just want to *add* this one, not replace all of the ones already there with it. If you want to remove the previous options:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
sel.options.length = 0;
sel.options.add(option);
```